# IOS9 beta shows a partially hidden SearchBar above the tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a question about default hiding the SearchBar in a TableView's TableHeaderView within IOS9 beta. It shows the tableview with a partially hidden SearchBar in IOS9 beta. I know IOS9 is still in Beta but I want to know if I am missing something here.

In IOS 7 and 8 the following code works perfect (as pointed out here many times on stackoverflow). By default, it hides the SearchBar when opening the tableview.

```
-(void)initFields
{
  NSString *strSearch = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSLocalizedString(@"search", nil), @"..."];

  UISearchBar *objSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
  objSearchBar.placeholder = strSearch;
  objSearchBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleDefault;
  objSearchBar.showsCancelButton=NO;
  objSearchBar.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
  objSearchBar.autocapitalizationType=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
  objSearchBar.delegate = self;

  self.SearchBar = objSearchBar;
  self.SearchBar.text = self.carFilter;

  self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.SearchBar;
}

-(void)initLayOut
{
  [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44) animated:NO];
}
```

In my case I first call the initFields function followed by the initLayout function. But I cannot figure out why in IOS9 beta the SearchBar is partially hidden above the tableview. I have tried different offsets but they all render the SearchBar partially.

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: As a beta tester you need to report any bugs to Apple. Put together a little test app demonstrating the issue and let them know.

Comment: I guess first you need to know whether it's s bug on Apple's side or not, and that is where SO comes in.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will inform Apple about the issue.

Comment: This keeps happening for me in 9.3 - did you get this solved? BTW do not capitalize property names - `self.SearchBar` vs. `self.searchBar`. This is not C# (thank heavens) and for both ObjC and Swift, the convention is to capitalize only type names.

Comment: @CharlieMonroe I did report this issue to apple and they marked it as duplicate and closed the issue. Engineering has determined that your bug report (21840991) is a duplicate of another issue (22106545) and will be closed. It seems that on real devices it does not happen. However, the problem is still within the simulators which is quite annoying. Thanx for pointing out the coding conventions :-)